# How to rewrite binomial coefficient as polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I have a binomial coefficient $\binom{n + 2}{3}$ and I need to rewrite it as a polynomial. I understand polynomials use addition, subtraction and multiplication of non-negative integers.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{(n+2)!}{3!(n+2-3)!}=\frac{(n+2)!}{3!(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{3!}(n+2)(n+1)n=\frac{n^{3}}{6}+\frac{n^{2}}{2}+\frac{n}{3}$$